# Discord.py rewrite and youtube_dl

Tags: python, youtube-dl, discord.py

I've been trying to create a discord bot for my server and I'm stuck on a problem.
How can I play music using youtube_dl without having to download it? Right now I'm using:

```
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
ydl.download([url])
```

It downloads the song, and then I play it. It works, but it takes around 15 seconds to do all of that, which isn't bad, but I was wondering if there was any way to make it faster? For example, Rythm Bot is instantaneous.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: I've done a lot of research, but I still haven't found a way to do it.
I'm trying to find a way to play songs instantly. This is what it does now:

-Gets URL from user;
-Downloads the song using that URL;
-Renames the downloaded song to 'song.mp3';
-Plays 'song.mp3'.

This process takes around 15 seconds, I was wondering if I could make it instantaneous, maybe like this:

-Gets URL from user;
-Opens the link and plays the song from YouTube.

Or maybe another way to make it faster, even by using a different library...?

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced the same error but found the solution for playing music instantly. When you run the play command, the bot downloads the music from YouTube. That's why it takes so long. But if you stream the music directly from YouTube, it should work instantly. Here is the code for directly streaming the music provided by Rapptz (i.e creator of Discord.py)

```
@commands.command()
async def stream(self, ctx, *, url):
    """Streams from a url (same as yt, but doesn't predownload)"""
    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
    ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
    await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(player.title))
```

You can find the full code here (check the stream function for your problem) : https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py